# When inserting into db insert a number in 2 different fields thats between 1-1000 and not already there

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I need to be able to insert a random value between 1-1000 in to the "left" field and a random value between 1-1000 in the "top" field or a database row - however I want it to check if the "left" and "top" dont already have the 2 proposed values?

lets say left has been randmomly assigned the value 23 and top has been randomly assigned the value 967, if in the database it has already got an entry with left being 23 and top being 967 then randomly assign 2 new values that are not taken?

Cheers

Comment: so what happens when all the numbers are taken?...

Comment: yes but just generating 2 random numbers and storing in db, but unable to even begin working out how to see if it already exists

Comment: Well, when all the numbers are taken, thats kind of the end of the project. so I can manaully stop more entrys in the db, but ideally an error message appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudocode, but it shows the sequence of events:

```
$exists = 1;

do
{
  // GENERATE $left and $top

  $query_results = /* SELECT * FROM table WHERE left = $left and top = $top */

  $exists = /* number of rows on $query_results */;

  if ($exist == 0)
  {
    // INSERT $left, $top INTO table
  }

}
while ($exists > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
$left = mt_rand(1,1000);

$top = mt_rand(1,1000);

while ($top == $left) {

    $top = mt_rand(1,1000);
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (left,top) VALUES (" . check($left, 'left') . ", " . check($top, 'top') . ")");

function check($input, $field) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table WHERE {$field} = {$input}");

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($row['count'] != 0) {

        check(mt_rand(1,1000), $field)
    }
    else {

        return $input;
    }
}
```

Then again recursive queries are no-no...

This is assuming `left` and `top` shouldn't equal each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
$n1 = rand(1,1000);
$n2 = rand(1,1000);

$link = mysql_connect(..);

$q = "select * from tbl where left = $n1 AND top = $n2";
$res = mysql_query($q,$link);

if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0)
{
   $q = "insert into tbl (left, top) values ($n1, $n2)";
   mysql_query($q, $link);
}

mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: But what happens when num_rows isn't 0?